# Using Advanced custom fields with Wordpress and everything works on local and fails miserably on production

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

[This is the thread I opened on ACF's website.](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-works-perfect-locally-completely-fails-live/)

[This is the website in question](http://www.mikaelasheldt.com/)

But basically my local version of the site works without a hitch but when I pushed it live it fails.

I haven't heard from the ACF guru in a couple days but, picking up where we left off, the closest I can figure the problem is has something to do with `get_the_id()` returning `int(1078)` instead of `int(1)` like it should being that the database is brand new and the "Hello World" is the first and only post.

What's also weird is the title is correct but and half of the content exists but nothing I've done can get it to display.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before? Is there a good reason why `get_the_id()` returns the right post id on my local installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to make a copy of your local database and replace every `localhost` with the correct site url. After that execute this SQL in your production environment. Probably your database is messed up.

Comment: Hmmm.. I didn't push my local DB live though, I just wanted my client to start with a fresh one.

Comment: I get that, but you could try it. If it works you know it has to do with your database.

Comment: I just went into phpMyadmin and I have no tables or anything, does that seem wrong? I'm not very good with the back end stuff yet.

Comment: If I navigate to your page I get a database error. Don't know what you've changed?

Comment: I just dropped all the old test DBs and am just making a new one since there was nothing on that one worth saving (just 'Hello World') hoping that starting from scratch with a new DB fixes it.

Comment: Hmmm, just went into config.php to update the credentials and there was a bunch of weird credentials I don't remember adding.

Comment: Just try what I said. First get a copy of you local database and paste this into notepad. Now replace every `localhost` with the site url. The weird credentials are probably from the setup. Wordpress will add these automatically.

Comment: Alright, gonna try this. I let you know what happens in a few minutes. Depending on my competency a few few minutes.

Comment: How do I just get a copy of my local that's paste-able into a text editor? In MAMP it's a bunch of folders?

Comment: Go to: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` --> Select your database --> Export --> Make sure that 'SQL' is selected in the dropdown menu --> Start

Comment: Does it matter if I choose quick or custom for my export method?

Comment: Quick will fit your needs

Comment: What's the best way to import this?

Comment: Just saved it as .txt and that seems to have worked. Am trying to reconnect to the DB via config.php now

Comment: VICTORY!!!!! Thank you so much!! PHP isn't my strongest language so I figured it had something to do some syntax error somewhere and have refactoring my code for a week trying to sort this out!! I never would have guessed it was DB problem on my own.